# Upload multiplr files using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need a open dialog to select many files and then I want to handle the files in controller. How should the view look like? I'm using aspx not razor.

with this code we can select just one file and then use it in controller

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="file" id="img1" name="img1" />
</div>
```

but what about selecting multiple files? (By Shift or Ctrl keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Upload for MVC3 Here: https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3. Is uses both a handler and it also has an example of an MVC3 action.